# set Delegate for a modal transition

Tags: ios

How do i set the delegate for a modal transition?

Currently I have something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)nextViewController:(NextViewController *)sender setSomething(NSString *)something
{
    NSLog(@"Something happened in nextviewcontroller");
}
```

This works if the transition is a push, but when it is a modal (arrow goes to a navigation controller) nothing happens.

Why is this and what is a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In prepareForSegue I needed to set the delegate to the topView of the navigation controller.

like this:

```
ExampleViewController *evc;
evc = (ExampleViewController *)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
[evc setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

are u using storyboard? if not, you should add navigation controller on the app delegate and pushviewcontroller will work